# Library for collecting PC hardware/OS info

Tags: c++, .net, profiling

Are there any free or opensource library for collecting PC hardware and operating system information like PC Wizard's System Information Dev Kit does?
I would like to prefer .NET assembly or native dll (so I can use it's functions through PInvoke), but Java one is fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried
[WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You can obtain probably all the information you want about the [hardware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [OS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392727%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).