# How do I detect the DirectX shader model above v3 supported by a graphics card?

Tags: directx, shader-model

I am writing a small utility that reports system capabilities. One is the highest shader model supported by the installed graphics card, and I am currently detecting this using [Direct3D 9.0c's device capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and checking the `VertexShaderVersion` and `PixelShaderVersion` fields of the `D3DCAPS9` structure.

```
HRESULT hrDCaps = poD3D9->GetDeviceCaps(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, &oCaps);
   if (!FAILED(hrDCaps)) {
      // Pixel and vertex shader model versions. Use the minimum number of each for "the" shader model version
      const int iVertexShaderModel = D3DSHADER_VERSION_MAJOR(oCaps.VertexShaderVersion);
      const int iPixelShaderModel = D3DSHADER_VERSION_MAJOR(oCaps.PixelShaderVersion);
```

However, both these values return shader model 3 even for cards that support higher models. Here is what GPU-Z returns for the same card, for example:

[image: GPU-Z showing shader model 4.1]

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976319/c-indicates-my-highest-shader-model-is-3) indicates that DX9 will never report more than SM3 even on cards that support a higher model, but doesn't actually mention how to solve it.

**How do I accurately get the shader model supported by the installed card?**  That is, the card capabilities, not the installed DirectX driver capabilities.

The utility has to run on Windows 2000 and above, and work on systems where a graphics card and even DirectX are not installed. I am currently dynamically loading DX9, so on those systems the check gracefully fails (which is ok.) But I am seeking a similar solution: something that will still run on *all* systems, and work correctly (detect the SM version) on *most* systems.

---

**Edit - purpose:** I am not using this code to dynamically change features of a program, ie select shaders. I am using it to report hardware capabilities as a 'ping' to a server, which is used to we have a good idea of typical hardware that our customers use, which can inform future product decisions.  (For example: how many customers have SM4 or above? How many are using a 64-bit OS? Etc.)  This is why either (a) gracefully failing, so we know it failed, or (b) getting an *accurate* shader model number are the two preferred modes.

**Edit - answers so far:** The answer below by SigTerm suggests instantiating DirectX 11, 10.1, 10, and 9.0c in order, and basing the reported shader model on which version instantiated without failures (shader model 5, 4.1, 4, and DXCAPS in that order.)  If possible, I'd appreciate a code example of the DX11 and 10 ways to do this.

This may not be a reliable solution. For example, I am running Windows on a VMWare Fusion virtual machine on OSX. The Fusion drivers report DX11 in DxDiag, yet I know from the Fusion tech specs that it [only supports DX9.0c and shader model 3](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/features.html). Still, with this exception, this method seems the best way so far.

Comment: Note that even if the hardware supports SM4+, you won't be able to use most of it from D3D9. There are a few odd driver features that sort of backport D3D10 stuff (like AMD's R2VB extensions), but you can't just load up a SM4 shader in D3D9.

Comment: Thanks peachykeen. I don't want to use it - I want to know if it's available. Using it comes later when we know that x% of our customers can use it, so it's worth coding for. Gathering those stats are what this little utility is for.

Answer (score 5):

version 4 is only supported on Direct3D10. Therefore, D3D9 api won't report it. Use D3D10/D3D11 api to detect higher version.

> something that will still run on all systems, and work correctly (detect the SM version) on most systems.

Attempt to initialize D3D10/D3D11 to check functionality, if it fails init D3D9. Use LoadLibrary + GetProcAddress to load D3D10 functions, because if you link with D3D10 using .lib file, your application will fail to start if d3d10 is missing.

Or use OpenGL and try to map capabilities reported by OpenGL to D3D capabilities (probably a very bad idea).

Or build GPU database and use that.

> where a graphics card and even DirectX are not installed.

I think you're asking for the impossible, because shaders are provided by DirectX, and the driver/GPU might not even have a concept of a "shader model" under the hood. In this case the only way to detect capabilites will be to make GPU database of some sort, detect installed devices, and return answer from database. This won't be relabile, of course.

Comment: If you need D3D10 features, trying to get a 10 context and checking the featureset is the best way. OpenGL shader features don't necessarily map to D3D (many older drivers support D3D somewhat better), and keeping a lookup table will cause nothing but problems and false negatives/positives. Trying to create a D3D9/10 context on first-run and checking caps isn't terribly slow and is very reliable. Just make sure not to link your program against D3D10 (or it won't run on systems without it, use LoadLibrary).

Comment: Thanks SigTerm and @peachykeen. "version 4 is only supported on Direct3D10. Therefore, D3D9 api won't report it." I had put that together from the linked question. *How* do I "Use D3D10/D3D11 api to detect higher version"? (Believe me, I have googled, and there are no results for things like getting capabilities, detecting the shader model, etc with D3D10. Nor can I find anything starting from the D3D10 device create method in MSDN, etc.) Ie, can you either write a method name as a pointer to google from, or even better a code snippet, please?

Comment: @DavidM: It looks like they dropped device caps in D3D10, so ALL d3d10 cards support ALL D3d10 capabilities. It looks like D3D10 supports SM4, D3D10.1 supports 4.1 and D3D11 supports SM5.

Comment: So... you try to instantiate, in order, DX11, DX10.1 and DX10, and from that derive the shader model version? One problem is that I'm running Windows on VMWare Fusion, which according to GPU-Z supports DX11 but only shader model 3.

Comment: @DavidM: That's how I would do it. I don't work with D3D10, but my guess is that this behavior would make card non-standard-compliant (or that GPU-Z has a bug). You could also investigate GPU-Z executables with `dumpbin /imports` and see what it actually calls. But that'll be a gray area / possible violation of licensing terms (not sure). Or search for opensource project that can do the same thing and tear it apart.

Comment: @DavidM: (IMO) Instead of writing your own tool, consider reusing existing solution, like GPU-Z. If there's already a free tool for a task, no point in writing another one. If you're working on a game engine and are trying to write some system requirements checker for your clients, then in case of graphics it might make sense to make a short demo/benchmark instead. If it works, game should work as well.  I mean it wasn't uncommon for older graphic driver to bluescreen the system on winxp. You can't check for things like this with D3DCaps.

Comment: I'm actually trying to write a small hardware reporting tool, to report back to a server so we have a good idea of what typical hardware our customers have, which will be useful for future product decisions. I can't re-use GPU-Z there and I don't know of (though feel free to suggest!) easily available libraries to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @DavidM: Hardware information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365380/library-for-collecting-pc-hardware-os-info . Also I'd try trace GPU-Z calls and see what it does, but that might be a violation of license agreement. For D3D initialization see DirectX tutorials in DirectX SDK. For your purposes, however, I think it would make sense to gather videocard names, ids, manufacturers, and amount of available video memory instead of checking for D3D shader. You can't use SM4+ on WinXP, for example, even if GPU could do that on Vista/7. Also I'd check GL extensions - might be useful in future.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [a link](http://compactiongames.about.com/od/systemrequirements/a/How-To-Determine-Direct-X-Version-And-Shader-Model-You-Are-Running.htm) about DirectX versions and supported shader models.